# Floating button is Hide in IOS app and not calling reload the table

Tags: ios

[image]
[image]

```
_setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:
    UIKit`+[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:]:
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call tableview's reload method in main Queue because animation works in a different thread .

replace your code

```
[_menuTable reloadData];
```

with

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_menuTable reloadData];
     });
```

Comment: Plz Mark answer as a right if this solved your problem.